# ¿Cómo imprimir fracciones consecutivas?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problema con mi codigo, ya puedo imprimir el resultado de las fracciones pero ahora quiero imprimir la secuencia de ellas por ejemplo esta foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi código solo imprime el resultado como la siguiente foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería que alguien me ayudara a imprimir la secuencia que es lo único que falta...

Dejo mi código aquí.

```html
<body> <!-- Se inicia el cuerpo del documento-->
   <form>  <!-- Se empieza un formulario-->
   <label for=""> Escribe el numero de fracciones a sumar:</label> <!-- Se agrega un text con la etiqeuta label-->
   <input type="text" id="nombre">                      <!-- Se especifica el tipo y nombre-->
   <br>                                                 <!-- se agrega un salto de linea-->                                           <!-- se agrega un salto de linea-->
   <button type="button" onclick="mostrar()">Ejecutar</button> <!-- Se agrega un boton con el nombre correspondiente-->
   <button type="button" onclick="limpiar()">Limpiar</button> <!-- Se agrega un boton con el nombre correspondiente-->
   <button type="button" onclick="salir()">Salir</button> <!-- Se agrega un boton con el nombre correspondiente-->
   <div id="solic"><!-- inicio de la division, se le da un nombre para poderlo utilizar despues  -->
   </div><!-- fin de la division  -->
   </form>
   </body><!--Se cierra el cuerpo del documento-->
```

```
function mostrar(){                               //se declara la funcion 
     var numero=document.getElementById('nombre').value;//se obtienen los valores de la caja de texto
        var r=1; //se declara una variable
        var n=1; //se declara una variable
        var d=2.0;//se declara una variable
        var suma=0;//se declara una variable

        if(numero>=1){//se inicializa la primera condicion
           for(var i=0;i<numero;i++){//se inicia un for para el conteo de la fraccion
           r= r *(n/d);//este sera la operacion que inicializara el resultado
           suma= suma + r;//esta variable guardara los resultados para irlos sumando
        }
        //for(var i=1;i<numero;i++){
        //valor 
        //}
        document.getElementById('solic').innerHTML=("La serie a sumar de la fraccion son"+"<br>"+ suma);//aqui devolveremos el dato en la pantalla web
     }//se cierra la primera condicion
     if(numero==0){//en caso de que el dato ssea igual a cero
        alert("Resultado incorrecto; \n No se puede realizar la suma por el dato: "+numero);// se arrojara una ventana de alerta 
     }//se cierra la condicion         
     else if(numero<0){//y en dado caso de que sea negativo
        alert("Resultado incorrecto; \n No se puede realizar la suma por el dato: "+numero);//se arrojara una ventana de alerta
     }//se cierra la condicion
  }//se termina la funcion
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Ya lo agrego enseguida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Necesitas un `for` para formar las fracciones asi:

```js
function mostrar(){                               //se declara la funcion 
     var numero=document.getElementById('nombre').value;//se obtienen los valores de la caja de texto
        var r=1; //se declara una variable
        var n=1; //se declara una variable
        var d=2.0;//se declara una variable
        var suma=0;//se declara una variable

        if(numero>=1){//se inicializa la primera condicion
           for(var i=0;i<numero;i++){//se inicia un for para el conteo de la fraccion
           r= r *(n/d);//este sera la operacion que inicializara el resultado
           suma= suma + r;//esta variable guardara los resultados para irlos sumando
        }
        var sequencia = "";
        var den = 1;
        for(var i=1;i<=numero;i++){
          den = 2 * den;
          sequencia += "1/" + (den) + " + ";
        }
        sequencia = sequencia.substring(0, sequencia.length - 2);
        document.getElementById('solic').innerHTML=("La serie a sumar de la fraccion son"+"<br>"+ sequencia + " = " + suma);//aqui devolveremos el dato en la pantalla web
     }//se cierra la primera condicion
     if(numero==0){//en caso de que el dato ssea igual a cero
        alert("Resultado incorrecto; \n No se puede realizar la suma por el dato: "+numero);// se arrojara una ventana de alerta 
     }//se cierra la condicion         
     else if(numero<0){//y en dado caso de que sea negativo
        alert("Resultado incorrecto; \n No se puede realizar la suma por el dato: "+numero);//se arrojara una ventana de alerta
     }//se cierra la condicion
  }//se termina la funcion
```

```html
<body> <!-- Se inicia el cuerpo del documento-->
   <form>  <!-- Se empieza un formulario-->
   <label for=""> Escribe el numero de fracciones a sumar:</label> <!-- Se agrega un text con la etiqeuta label-->
   <input type="text" id="nombre">                      <!-- Se especifica el tipo y nombre-->
   <br>                                                 <!-- se agrega un salto de linea-->                                           <!-- se agrega un salto de linea-->
   <button type="button" onclick="mostrar()">Ejecutar</button> <!-- Se agrega un boton con el nombre correspondiente-->
   <button type="button" onclick="limpiar()">Limpiar</button> <!-- Se agrega un boton con el nombre correspondiente-->
   <button type="button" onclick="salir()">Salir</button> <!-- Se agrega un boton con el nombre correspondiente-->
   <div id="solic"><!-- inicio de la division, se le da un nombre para poderlo utilizar despues  -->
   </div><!-- fin de la division  -->
   </form>
   </body><!--Se cierra el cuerpo del documento-->
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alan.

Comment: Sería mucha molestia que me expliques tu lógica?

Comment: Necesitas concatenar las fracciones en la variable `sequencia`.  Tambien necesitas una variable para el denominador.  La sequencia del denominador es el denominador anterior multiplicado por 2 empezando con 2.  Finalmente, remueves el signo `+` que queda al ultimo con `substring()` y listo.

Comment: Muchas gracias alan la verdad se me ocurrió algo así pero no sabía de que manera hacerlo, gracias por ayudarme de verdad.